# Where can I download the API for Umbraco?

Tags: api, umbraco

I am a bit confused here. In this [example](http://goo.gl/iueob) someone is using the API to create a document, that is exactly what I need. The problem is that I don't seam to find the        actual API DLLs they recommend in the same example: *Remember to add the cms.dll, businesslogic.dll and umbraco.dll to your project* for instance.

What is it I need to download in order to build and application that uses this API?

Comment: I found the DLLs in the Umbraco installation bin folder. Yet, how do I configure them (tell them where umbraco is)?

Comment: In that case you must interface towards the database check the web.config of an installed site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is more than a year late and you may have figured this out already. But here you go.

You may start a new project (could be a library, a web application), then add references to those dlls. When that's done, you may now use the Umbraco API to create your business logic.

All you need to remember now is that you will need to copy your new project's dll to the bin directory of your umbraco installation after you build it. You will also need to copy related files such as ascx or ashx if you've created those.